# Why do request parameters sent in request body need to be URL encoded?

Tags: http, post, get, request, url-encoding

I understand with GET request they need to be entered into a URL and therefore need to be URL (percent) encoded so that they don't mean anything in the context of a server interpreting the URL.

But if data is in the body of a request rather than the URL then why does it need to be URL encoded?

Example:

[image]

Comment: That request is sent with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which says "My body is url encoded" - so it must be url encoded.  As to why the encoding is needed at all see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073451/246342

Comment: If it's not url-encoded, you will not, in general, be able to uniquely parse the string into key-value pairs. Regardless of whether it's in the url (get) or in the body, the url-encoding ensures there is no ambiguity in understanding what has been sent.

Comment: @AlexK. thanks for forwarding me that question, that one gives very good insight into what's actually happening.

Comment: I have the exact same question. Did you find a definite answer?

Comment: @FlorianWalther the answer is that when we use POST, data is still submitted as a series of name=value pairs. Therefore we still need to url encode so that we can't have things like '=' or '&' in the value which will mes up the parsing of the values on the server. :)

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. No one really explains this anywhere, it's crazy.